# There is any method for webview cache Optimization in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, optimization, flutter-inappwebview

I use flutter_inappwebview for fetching the website into the flutter app. I want to save all the resources like JS and CSS file content into the cache from website during webview start and then when I call same website the resources will intercept and inject the cached files into the webview. Is this possible.. If possible then how.. please explain with example. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/blob/master/lib/src/webview_options.dart) package has already a property, cacheEnabled with default parameter, true. You don't need to do anything about this. If you don't want to store cache files, then you can set it to false.

```
 ///Sets whether WebView should use browser caching. The default value is `true`.
 ///
 ///**NOTE**: available on iOS 9.0+.
 bool cacheEnabled;
```

And, the clearCache property with the default value, 'false'.

```
///Set to `true` to have all the browser's cache cleared before the new WebView is opened. The default value is `false`.
bool clearCache;
```

Answer (score 1):

note: caching is already enabled for this plugin by default. but what you're asking is offline-mode which [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin does not support yet.

the cache you're refering to is not the cache that browsers use (mobile or desktop) what you're refering to is basically called offline-mode in the world of browsers.

in regard to the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin there is already an issue (or two) about this feature you're looking for. and i believe it is not implemented yet.

you should keep an eye on these github issues [issue-561](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/561) & [issue-366](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/366)